# Activity in tabhost android?

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I wanted diffrent activities in tabs here is the code I have written but the application is constantly crashing what is going on here?

```
TabHost th = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    th.setup();

 TabSpec specs1 = th.newTabSpec("tag2");

    specs1.setIndicator("Tab 2");
    specs1.setContent(new Intent(this, Songs.class));
    th.addTab(specs1);
```

any help would be appritated thank u

EDIT

this is what I get in LogCat

```
 11-29 23:23:06.490: D/AndroidRuntime(299): Shutting down VM
 11-29 23:23:06.490: W/dalvikvm(299): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
 11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget   to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
 11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:649)
 11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):  at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):  at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:453)
11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
 11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
```

11-29 23:23:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(299):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: post your logcat.and make sure you are extending TabActivity and not just Activity!

Comment: Have you registered the Activity in the manifest file?

Comment: I think u have to use TabHost th = getTabHost();

Comment: I am extending activity so I can't go getTabHost();

Comment: here is what I got "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?"

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to Debug in Eclipse and how to use the [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) and [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618172953/http://developer.android.com:80/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) tools.

In order to get more details about an exception/force close you need to look for a view in Eclipse called [Logcat](https://web.archive.org/web/20100324231958/http://developer.android.com:80/intl/de/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html)(you will find in the [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20170825232742/http://www.brighthub.com:80/mobile/google-android/articles/25023.aspx) perspective) there you will find a detailed traceback when/what and on what line is the issue.

For this you should read a complete article about [Debugging in Android using Eclipse](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [droidnova.com](http://www.droidnova.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/debugging-3.gif))</sub>

Comment: This is not an answer.  It is a comment on how better to uncover the problem.

Comment: I have put in the logcat report please help me out if possible thanks!